How to combine CLI message with purrr family functions
I am wondering how to convert this example code to purrr style by using the walk() function instead?
library(cli)

n <- 10
cli_alert_info("About to start downloads of {n} file{?s}")

i <- 0
cli_progress_step("Got {i}/{n} {qty(i)}file{?s}.")

for (i in seq_len(n)) {
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
  cli_progress_update()
}

Any comments and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

You could use the .progress argument. See Progress bars in purrr for more details.
library(cli)

n <- 10
cli_alert_info("About to start downloads of {n} file{?s}")

purrr::walk(seq_len(n), ~ {
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
}, .progress = list(type = "iterator",
                    format = "Got {pb_current}/{pb_total} {qty(pb_current)}file{?s}.",
                    clear = FALSE))

# ℹ About to start downloads of 10 files
# Got 10/10 files.


Thank you Darren. I am just wondering where are pb_current and pb_total defined? (I tried with other values but they didn't work) , or they are terms reserved for this specific usage?

@Grasshopper_NZ They are defined in progress bar variables from {cli} package.
